# From/To filter for numeric columns in jQuery Tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Looking at this example:

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-1.html

How can I set the From/To filter (with two text input fields) like in the last Date column but in a numbers only column, like Total column in that example above?

As in, I don't want the slider in the Total column, I want the two From/To fields instead. Is that possible? And how? Which plugin/widget do I need to use and with what parameters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will end up writing your own [custom filter formatter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-1.html#custom_filter_formatter_function_information) to add two numeric input fields; it isn't that straight-forward, but most of the code from the [jQuery UI datepicker (2 inputs) formatter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/widgets/widget-filter-formatter-jui.js#L618) can be copied & modified to suit your needs.

In a future update, I plan to replace the `filter_formatter` functions with an option that only needs to return a query value for a column. This change will enable developers to build their own custom filter row with a custom UI and not be limited by the code available for the `filter_formatter`.

---

Ok, here you go ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/522/))

```
/*! Widget: filter formatter functions - created 6/24/2015 *//*
 * requires: tableSorter (FORK) 2.15+ and jQuery 1.4.3+
 *
 * number range - 2 number inputs
 */
/*jshint browser:true, jquery:true, unused:false */
/*global jQuery: false */
;(function($){
"use strict";

var ts = $.tablesorter || {},

tsff = ts.filterFormatter = $.extend( {}, ts.filterFormatter, {

    /*************************\
    2 number inputs
    \*************************/
    inputs: function($cell, indx, defNumber) {
        var o = $.extend({
            // filter formatter options
            textFrom : 'from',
            textTo : 'to',
            from : 0, // "from" input
            to : 100, // "to" input
            callback: function($cell){}
        }, defNumber),
        closeNumber,
        $shcell = [],
        c = $cell.closest('table')[0].config,
        // Add a hidden input to hold the range values
        $input = $('<input class="numberRange" type="hidden">')
            .appendTo($cell)
            // hidden filter update namespace trigger by filter widget
            .bind('change' + c.namespace + 'filter', function(){
                var v = this.value;
                if (v.match(' - ')) {
                    v = v.split(' - ');
                    $cell.find('.numberTo').val(v[1]);
                    closeNumber(v[0]);
                } else if (v.match('>=')) {
                    closeNumber( v.replace('>=', '') );
                } else if (v.match('<=')) {
                    closeNumber( v.replace('<=', '') );
                }
            }),

        // make sure we're using parsed numbers in the search
        $hdr = c.$headerIndexed[ indx ].addClass('filter-parsed'),
        // Add range picker
        t = '<label>' + o.textFrom + '</label><input type="number" class="numberFrom" placeholder="' +
            ($hdr.data('placeholderFrom') || $hdr.attr('data-placeholder-from') || c.widgetOptions.filter_placeholder.from || '') + '" />' +
            '<label>' + o.textTo + '</label><input type="number" class="numberTo" placeholder="' +
            ($hdr.data('placeholderTo') || $hdr.attr('data-placeholder-to') || c.widgetOptions.filter_placeholder.to || '') + '" />';
        $(t).appendTo($cell);

        closeNumber = function( selectedNumber ) {
            var range,
                from = $cell.find('.numberFrom').val(),
                to = $cell.find('.numberTo').val();
            range = from ? ( to ? from + ' - ' + to : '>=' + from ) : (to ? '<=' + to : '');
            $cell.add( $shcell )
                .find('.numberRange').val(range)
                .trigger('search');

            if (/<=/.test(range)) {
                $cell.add( $shcell )
                    .find('.numberFrom').val( to || 0 ).end()
                    .find('.numberTo').val( to || 0 );
            } else if (/>=/.test(range)) {
                $cell.add( $shcell )
                    .find('.numberFrom').val( from || 0 ).end()
                    .find('.numberTo').val( from || 0 );
            } else {
                $cell.add( $shcell )
                    .find('.numberFrom').val( from || 0 ).end()
                    .find('.numberTo').val( to || 0 );
            }

            if (typeof o.callback === 'function') { o.callback($cell); }
        };

        $cell.add( $shcell )
            .find('.numberFrom')
            .val( o.from ).end()
            .find('.numberTo')
            .val( o.to ).end()
            .find('.numberFrom, .numberTo')
            .bind('change', function(){
                closeNumber();
            });

        // update date compare from hidden input, in case of saved filters
        c.$table.bind('filterFomatterUpdate', function(){
            var val = $input.val() || '',
                from = o.from,
                to = o.to;
            // date range
            if (/\s+-\s+/.test(val)){
                val = val.split(/\s+-\s+/) || [];
                from = val[0] || '';
                to = val[1] || '';
            } else if (/>=/.test(val)) {
                // greater than date (to date empty)
                from = val.replace(/>=/, '') || '';
            } else if (/<=/.test(val)) {
                // less than date (from date empty)
                to = val.replace(/<=/, '') || '';
            }

            $cell.add($shcell).find('.numberFrom').val( from || 0 );
            $cell.add($shcell).find('.numberTo').val( to || 0 );
            // give datepicker time to process
            setTimeout(function(){
                closeNumber();
                ts.filter.formatterUpdated($cell, indx);
            }, 0);
        });

        // has sticky headers?
        c.$table.bind('stickyHeadersInit', function(){
            $shcell = c.widgetOptions.$sticky.find('.tablesorter-filter-row').children().eq(indx).empty();
            $shcell.append(t);

            // add a jQuery datepicker!
            $shcell.find('.numberFrom').val( o.from );
            $shcell.find('.numberTo').val( o.to );

        });

        // on reset
        $cell.closest('table').bind('filterReset', function(){
            $cell.add($shcell).find('.numberFrom').val( o.from || 0 );
            $cell.add($shcell).find('.numberTo').val( o.to || 0 );
            setTimeout(function(){
                closeNumber();
            }, 0);
        });

        // return the hidden input so the filter widget has a reference to it
        return $input.val( o.from ? ( o.to ? o.from + ' - ' + o.to : '>=' + o.from ) : (o.to ? '<=' + o.to : '') );
    }

});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Jesus... I just had a heart attack looking at all that code. I might have to hire someone to do that for me, as I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: LOL yeah, dates are a lot more complicated than numbers.

Comment: Can I hire you to do that modification quickly for me?

Comment: Oh wow... that is incredible. And not a single flaw I can see in testing it. Thank you!!!

Comment: one question - how do I bind an onChange function to the filter fields? I've tried this:  $('.tablesorter-filter,.select2-input').on('change',function(){ console.log("it's working..."); });   But I get nothing... what am I missing?